# The usage of globalize in sentences

Tags: word-usage

"globalize" is often used with company or system. I am wondering if the sentences below are  correct when it comes to the topic of disease.

1. The COVID-19 pandemic has globalized.
2. The COVID-19 pandemic is globalized.
3. COVID-19 has become a global pandemic.

Comment: The *noun* form ***globalisation*** has shot to prominence over the past couple of decades, but I've rarely if ever heard *[to] **globalise*** used as a verb, and even the "adjectival" past tense verb *(This industry has become globalised)* isn't common. And I'm quite sure I've never *ever* heard the "intransitive / reflexive verb" usage *This industry has globalised*.

Comment: ...note that there's little connection between *a global pandemic* (which ***reaches*** across the world) and *a globalised industry* (which is ***interconnected*** across the world).

Comment: If a disease is pandemic, it has spread all over the world. A pandemic is a global epidemic. "Covid-19 has become a pandemic."

Comment: has become global. Forget globalise.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, none of these sentences correct.

## "global"

> COVID-19 has become a global pandemic.

A pandemic is - by definition - a disease that is spread across the world, so saying "global pandemic" is redundant. Otherwise, though, the sentence is fine. For example, you could say any of the following:

> COVID-19 has become a global problem.

> The conflict between Ukraine and Russia has become a global concern.

> My favorite singer has become a global phenomenon!

## "globalize"

Some dictionaries may define "globalize" as "to make global" but that definition is misleading because it is too simple. Instead, "globalization" (which is the variation English speakers tend to use) describes how something is changed from working at local level to working at a global level.

The term is often used broadly, referring to how our world has become more interconnected than it was in the past, without mentioning what things specifically have been globalized. The word "globalization" is most frequently used when discussing business and politics, but can be relevant to discussions about disease.

Here are a few example sentences.

> Globalization means diseases can spread more widely, making pandemics more likely.

> Businesses that properly adapted to globalization will greatly benefit from access to global markets.

> It is widely believed that many Americans have lost their jobs due to globalization because factories have been moved overseas.

Comment: Globalize definitely seems more common in past or present participle, or as globalization. But [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/globalize) (in "recent examples on the Web") quotes *Variety* "Uncle Waffles, credited for helping globalize South African music, dazzled the crowd with her signature *amapiano* vibes and dance moves." This sounds OK to me. Using "globalize" with COVID sounds a bit less felicitous, if only because it's quite vague and certainly doesn't imply going all around the world or even to most of the world.